# Android webView - How to set upload file to image only?

Tags: android, android-webview

I have a html form which allows users to upload image file. It's working fine in web browsers and allows to select only image file. But doing the same in android application , users can able to select any file. I used the code from [here](https://github.com/mgks/Os-FileUp/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/inf/os/fileup/MainActivity.java).
I want to limit this to image file only in webView and the code also allows to choose camera,can I remove that too?

I tried changing the setType in **openFileChooser** but it's not helpful. Please help.

```
i.setType("image/*");
```

Comment: you can check the extension of the file(.jpg, .png ...)

Comment: i added the extensions but nothing changes.

Comment: What I meant is you must check the extension of the file while selecting the file, you should do it programmatically